# Using break and return in Java's synchronizedList performs unwanted behavior

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm new at using synchronizedLists in Java, and I'm running into a problem - I'm trying to do something like this

```
public void foo(List<String> list) {
   List<String> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
   synchronized(syncList) {
      Iterator<String> itr = syncList.iterator();
      while(itr.hasNext()) {
         String s = itr.next();
         if(s == null) {
            return;
         }
         doStuff();
      }
   }
}
```

But I've noticed that when I run this doStuff() doesn't seem to be run on each of the non-null items in the list. I've tried experimenting with swapping out return for break and continue, and I've found that doStuff() is also not run on the non-null list items with break. With continue, the non-null list items do get doStuff() run on them but since continue just skips to the next iteration of the loop it makes this operation much more expensive than desired.

Why is this happening and what is the best workaround?

edit: Forgot to add that when I run this sequentially with return, it works fine.

Comment: Use `continue` instead of `return` or `break`.

Comment: Or, better, `s != null`. I don't understand why `continue` would be inefficient. `continue` generally makes code harder to understand, but it is not in anyway inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` exits the loop. It makes execution jump to the first line of code outside the loop.

`return` exits the function, and naturally the loop contained in the function. The execution continues where this function was called.

> With continue, the non-null list items do get doStuff() run on them but since continue just skips to the next iteration of the loop it makes this operation much more expensive than desired.

I don't understand - what operation is more expensive in what way than you desire?

Either way, nothing here has to do with synchronization or parallel programming. The way `Collections.synchronizedList` and `synchronized(syncList)` are being used is pointless: there's no way another thread can access them.

Comment: I meant that running foo() in this case is more expensive than I desire. My overall goal is to speed up foo(), by allowing iterations of the loop to be run concurrently. Could you please explain more as to why it's pointless to use the synchronizedList here? Sorry, very new to using these.

Comment: This method `foo` runs `doStuff` exactly once for each non-null item in the list. In what way is that more expensive than you desire?

Comment: "Synchronization" is needed when two ore more threads have access to shared state. With the way `synchronizedList` and `synchronized` are used here, `syncList` can only be accessed by the thread that calls the method. There's no way other threads can get to it, so there is no shared state.

Comment: @Joni “there is no shared state” is not the right description. As you said correctly, the synchronized list is not shared, so there is no synchronization. The list passed in as a parameter still may be shared, so the correct statement would be that there is no thread-safety here.